# Difference of wrapping ternary conditional in squared and round brackets

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using squared and round brackets when used within a ternary conditional? For example:

squared: `[ x == y ? 1 : 0 ]`

round: `( x == y ? 1 : 0 )`

I know that `[ ]` are used for getting a arrays variable or a key from an associative array. Often however they are used in conjunction with things that have little to do with an array.

For example here is a small piece of a plugin I wrote:

```
(x.nodeType == 3 ? textContent : innerHTML)
```

The same only works using squared brackets but not round ones like above. It is as if the first returns something and the second one actually displays it.

Comment: `[...]` creates an array and `(...)` returns whatever the expression inside resolves to. E.g. `var foo = [true ? 1 : 2];` results in `foo` having the array `[1]` and `var foo = (true ? 1 : 2);` results in `foo` having the number `1`. What to use depends on what you want to achieve or the API / context of the remaining code.

Comment: Apart from what @FelixKling said, the bracket notation `[]` can also be used to access a property of an object `myObject["myProperty"]` or an index of an array `myArray[1]`. There's no further magic.

Comment: Need more context to understand why you say something only works with `[]` otherwise issue is not clear at all

Comment: @FelixKling that explained thing. I was a bit confused so thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounded brackets are used to evaluate a certain expression (in this case a ternary conditional) while square ones are used for creating an array, for accessing an array's position (for example if you have `var a = [1, 2, 3];` then `a[0]` is 1, a `[1]` is 2 and so on.) or for accessing object properties (in case you have `var a = {name : "John", age : 25};` then `a["age"]` is 25)

Take this as an example :

```
var b = [x == y ? 1 : 0]
```

will assign b to a new array having either 1 or 0

```
var b = (x == y ? 1 : 0)
```

will assing b either 1 or 0 (depending on x == y)

Hope it's clear

Comment: *"or for accessing an array's position"* Bracket notation can be used to access any *object property* not just properties/elements of arrays.

Comment: That explained it. I was not really sure so thanks a lot!

Comment: Furthermore, a `x == y ? 1 : 0` ternary expression can be shortened to `+(x==y)`, since `1` is truthy and `0` is falsy.  Not very useful, but I thought it was cool.